# Is there a way to set app-specific volume?

Tags: volume-control

I'm looking for a way to set the media volume depending on the app being used.

I generally keep my media volume down fairly low so as not to annoy my fellow humans overmuch; while playing Angry Birds, for instance.

When I go into Doggcatcher, though, I generally want to crank the media volume way up, because I'm listening through earbuds or my car speakers and need that volume way up.

Not such a big deal, but if later I go back to Angry Birds and I forgot to turn the volume back down it wakes up the whole house.

This is exacerbated by the fact that the media volume does not follow the "Sound off" setting (accessed by a long-press of the power button).

So, is there a way to do what I want?

*(Android 4.0)*

Answer (score 2):

My solution is tested on Android 4.2.1 and 5.0.2. There are three apps I'm aware of which can do the job here.

## [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

It's a paid app but works well for the objective.

1. Create a profile in it using `+`→**Application** → select your app.
2. Create a task in it, then an action using `+` → **Audio → Media Volume**.
3. Set the **Level** to the sound level you want in your app. (Hint: if you're running a music in background you would notice changes in the sound if you move the slider, thereby helping you to choose the level efficiently).

That's it. Play some music in the background, open the app you selected in instructions, and you would notice instant reduction in sound. Close the app and the sound level would return to the setting that were in place before launching the app.

## [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage)

It has two versions. The freeware can do the job but I didn't test if it has limits on active rules for being free.

1. Under **My Rules** tap **Add Rule**.
2. Choose **Application Status Trigger**  under **Trigger**.
3. Tap the lens icon under **Application** → select your app → tap **Next**.
4. Choose **Set Volume for Single Stream Action** under **Action**.
5. Move the slider to desired sound level → choose **Music Stream** → tap **Next**.
6. Choose **Default** or **No** if you want to see a toast  when the rule gets triggered → tap the floppy icon in the title bar to save the rule.

Now launch the app that you selected in this part of instructions and the media  volume would go down with the launch. Sadly, in contrast to Tasker, the volume doesn't revert back to previous settings.

To overcome that, you may create a new application based rule featuring your  launcher app and tweak the sound level under **Music Stream** action as we did earlier.

## [Automate - Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

This is also a freeware and is said to be user friendly yet powerful app. Unfortunately, I don't how to use this app other than performing a rudimentary task. Regardless, it has a block (action) under **Tools** named **Audio Volume Set** which you may use to get the job done.

As for instructions of using this app, the app will show you the basic usage on the first run. And I already told you where to look for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tasker or a similar scripting app, then i guess you could "record" a sequence of actions to be undertaken each time a particular app is started / in focus.