# Does Android support individual sound control per app when two apps with active sound are running?

Tags: volume-control

Does Android support controlling volume of every running app individually in the context mentioned below?

I have podcast app and I would like to run a game **while listening to podcast**. The game sounds are too high.

The question [Is there a way to set app-specific volume?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17414/96277) deals with an objective of having **per-app specific volume** but this question at the minimum deals with two or more apps at a time, providing different sound levels simultaneously.

Comment: @AlEverett this is not answer to my question. ITS rather workaround for particular problem the user had...

Comment: It's still a duplicate to your *question*, asking the same thing. May sound harsh, but that's how this site works: if your question is already there, you shouldn't ask it again. Suggestions include upvoting it and/or placing a [bounty](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to encourage new/better/additional answers. I admit, hard for new users – as for doing so they first must build up some rep...

Comment: It is not the same question because the user ask about setting of volume to one app at the time. I ask about setting volume of two apps at the time. And while the first question could be answered with workaround, my not.

Comment: I did some big changes into the question, yet tried to maintain the meaning. See if that's OK with you.

Comment: @Izzy Actually, I agree with Paul that this is not a duplicate of the marked question. Rather, a [question I've bountied](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/92530/131868) (which is open) seems to be a duplicate of Paul's question here. Paul was the first to ask it. The one I bountied (which I believe is as an exact duplicate of this one) was actually asked later.

Comment: @Fiksdal it's linked now that you've mentioned it. This Q here being from 2013, it makes no sense to re-open and re-close as dupe of something else ;) Thanks for the pointer, though!