# App Audio Mixer for Samsung Dex

Tags: samsung-dex, audio-controls

Is there an audio mixer setting to adjust the audio volume of individual open apps, like there is on Windows, built into Samsung Dex? Or do I need a 3rd party app for this?

Comment: The [same question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92530) has been posted some years ago, not sure if the answers are still valid.

Comment: @Robert The top answer in the linked question mentioned Samsung's Sound Assistant app, which is exactly what I'm looking for. So the answer is still valid.