# How to silence all but one application? (no calls, messages, notifications and similar interruptions)

Tags: audio, silent-mode

When listening to meditation instructions (previously downloaded as *.mp3 files) I would like to be able to silence all applications, (that is, all *audible* notifications, messages and calls). How?

---

PS: Native solution(s) which are *not* reliant on 3rd-party apps are prefered.

Comment: At least related: [Is there a way to set app-specific volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17414/16575) / [Control volume of particular app](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55624/16575)

Comment: Android version?

Comment: @Firelord kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any 3rd-party apps, then you have to learn programming and make your own.

In my opinion, the best way to do this is using [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage).
Its normal features include "Set volume" actions and if you register an account, then you could download one Pro codec, like the "Multiple(OR)" event that, could also be used when more than one app are opened.

All types of volume can be changed when a certain event happens.